# MySQL store latitude, longitude with high level precision

Tags: mysql, types, storage, latitude-longitude

I'm currently storing lat/lng values in a database with a 6 decimal place precision. However, some values that I need to store in this database have a 12 decimal precision. My database currently sets lat and long ast

FLOAT (10, 6)

Is it possible to set the storage type so that it can handle either 6 decimal or 12 decimal lat/lng values?

Comment: A lat/lon position described by 12 decimal places equates to micrometer precision.  I am curious as to what application needs to describe a position on earth to the micrometer level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `DOUBLE` data type.

You should be able nondestructively to alter your existing table to work this way. For example,

```
alter table `mytable` 
   change `LAT` `LAT` double NULL , 
   change `LONG` `LONG` double NULL
```

But be careful not to overstate your data's accuracy. The epsilon of an ordinary `float` 32-bit floating point lat/long value (the best possible accuracy) is a few centimeters on the ground.  The epsilon of a `double` is a tiny tiny distance.  It is almost inconceivable that your lat/long information is that precise.  And if it is, it really won't matter unless you're using sophisticated cartographic projections: the typical haversine formula for computing distances assumes that the earth is a perfect sphere.  It isn't. The equatorial bulge of the earth is big enough to make the spherical assumption break down for distances more precise than, again, a few centimeters.

Here's Randall Munroe's (XKCD) take on geocoordinate precision:

[image]

Comment: Note: when Ollie states the best possible accuracy for a float is a few centimeters, that is only true around the lat/lon point 0,0 (where the prime meridian meets the equator).  In the US, it is impossible to describe a position with centimeters accuracy with a float.  It is best to use a double for lat/lon.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at using spacial extensions.. 
Check out this link

[MYSQL and using Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)